# IconButton change position when click in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am using `IconButton` in my project. I am opening `Dialog` when I am click on `IconButton`. Whenever I clicked on `IconButton` the dialog opens and `IconButton` little bit shifts other side and back to position when `Dialog` close. You can see in this [video](https://youtu.be/ttRdoBg3zGQ). So what is the problem of this? I want to avoid this..

**OptionItemStateFul**

```
@Composable
fun OptionItemStateFul() {
    val isOptionItemClickAction = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    OptionItemStateLess(isOptionItemClickAction) {
        DialogOptionsView(
            openDialogCustom = isOptionItemClickAction,
            dialogOptionsData = DialogOptionsData(headerText = "Hi There", itemsList = listOf(1, 2)),
        )
    }
}
```

**OptionItemStateLess**

```
@Composable
fun OptionItemStateLess(
    isOptionItemClickAction: MutableState<Boolean>,
    onOptionItemClickAction: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    ) {
        Text(
            text = " itemName 1 item 2",
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(vertical = 13.dp)
                .weight(1f),
            maxLines = 1,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
        )
        OptionItemLabel(isOptionItemClickAction, onOptionItemClickAction)
    }
}
```

**OptionItemLabel**

```
@Composable
fun OptionItemLabel(
    isOptionItemClickAction: MutableState<Boolean>,
    onOptionItemClickAction: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    IconButton(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 10.dp),
        onClick = { isOptionItemClickAction.value = true }
    ) {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_menu),
            contentDescription = null,
            tint = Aqua,
        )
    }
    AnimatedVisibility(isOptionItemClickAction.value) {
        onOptionItemClickAction()
    }
}
```

**PreviewOptionItemStateFul**

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun PreviewOptionItemStateFul() {
    OptionItemStateFul()
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This change is coming because the dialog is in the row, so the dialog should be kept outside the row. Like this

**updated - OptionItemStateLess**

```
@Composable
fun OptionItemStateLess(
    isOptionItemClickAction: MutableState<Boolean>,
    onOptionItemClickAction: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    ) {
        Text(
            text = " itemName 1 item 2",
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(vertical = 13.dp)
                .weight(1f),
            maxLines = 1,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
        )
        OptionItemLabel(isOptionItemClickAction)
    }
    AnimatedVisibility(isOptionItemClickAction.value) {
        onOptionItemClickAction()
    }
}
```

**updated - OptionItemLabel**

```
@Composable
fun OptionItemLabel(
    isOptionItemClickAction: MutableState<Boolean>
) {
    IconButton(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 10.dp),
        onClick = { isOptionItemClickAction.value = true }
    ) {
        Icon(
            Icons.Default.Menu,
            contentDescription = null,
        )
    }
}
```